# Discord.js reaction role fetch message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was working on a reaction role and I got a problem that when I restart my server, the bot just ignores olrder messages and I must create new ones in order to work.

I tried this solution ([Listening for reactions on old messages](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#listening-for-reactions-on-old-messages)) but it doesn't seem to work, or I did something wrong.

Note that I am using discord.js version 12.

My code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "pol",
    description: "pol",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
        const vedorole = "925381200967786556";

        if (message.member.roles.cache.has(vedorole)) {
            const channel = "927868012659372082";

            const girl = message.guild.roles.cache.get("920379402422980638");
            const man = message.guild.roles.cache.get("925359181324767292");

            const girlEmoji = "";
            const manEmoji = "‍";

            const polembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("#000000")
                .setTitle("Izaberite pol")
                .setDescription(`\u200B`)
                .addFields({ name: `Žensko: ${girlEmoji}`, value: `*(Reagirajte da dobijete ${girl} role!)*` }, { name: "\u200B", value: "\u200B" }, { name: `Muško: ${manEmoji}`, value: `*(Reagirajte da dobijete ${man} role!)*` });

            let MessageEmbed = await message.channel.send(polembed);
            MessageEmbed.react(girlEmoji);
            MessageEmbed.react(manEmoji);

            client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user) => {
                if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
                if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
                if (user.bot) return;
                if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

                if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                    if (reaction.emoji.name === girlEmoji) {
                        reaction.message.reactions.cache.find((reaction) => reaction.emoji.name == manEmoji).users.remove(user.id);
                        reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(girl);
                    }

                    if (reaction.emoji.name === manEmoji) {
                        reaction.message.reactions.cache.find((reaction) => reaction.emoji.name == girlEmoji).users.remove(user.id);

                        reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(man);
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });

            client.on("messageReactionRemove", async (reaction, user) => {
                if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
                if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
                if (user.bot) return;
                if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

                if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                    if (reaction.emoji.name === girlEmoji) {
                        reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(girl);
                    }
                }

                if (reaction.emoji.name === manEmoji) {
                    reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(man);
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            });
        } else {
            message.channel.send("Nemate permisiju da izvršite ovu komandu!");
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to listen to events inside a command, because when `messageReactionAdd` is triggered it will execute the code block within it as many times as you ran the `pol` command.

Comment: What should I do? Put code to fetch message in index.js so it works?